# Compactness Theorem (logic) application.

Tags: logic, compactness, first-order-logic, model-theory

I met a question which says: if we have $A, B$, both are nonempty theories such that every model of $A$ satisfies at least one formula (sentence if they are in the first-order language, the question indicates that there is no difference whether it's propositional or first-order) in $B$. Then it asks me to show there are some formulas/sentences, $a_1....a_k$ from $A$ and $b_1...b_l$ from $B$ such that $(a_1...\land...a_k)\to(b_1...\lor...b_l)$ is a tautology.

The question specifically says I should use the compactness theorem, but I don't see how to apply the theorem here. Any hints?

Comment: Hint: Using the condition "every model of A satisfies at least one sentence in B", try to come up with a set of sentences that is inconsistent. Then apply compactness theorem to that set.

Comment: @halrankard2, so you mean, we need to first separate if B is satisfiable or not? If B is not satisfiable, then we just pick some b and not b so that it will be a tautology. But if B is satisfible, how to use the condition to construct such a set?

Comment: Analyzing whether or not B is satisfiable isn't fully leveraging the main connection between A and B. You know that every model of A is a model of some sentence in B. Therefore there is a certain collection of sentences (built using *both* A and B as ingredients) that is inconsistent.

Comment: @halrankard2 Still can't have a clue...Can you give an example? Why exactly there must be an inconsistent set...

Comment: Well it's hard to make an example that doesn't give away the answer. But suppose B consisted of just one sentence $\phi$. Then your assumption is that every model of A is a model of $\phi$. So $A\cup\{\neg\phi\}$ is an inconsistent set.

Comment: @halrankard2 My actual question is, why we need to use the compactness theorem. You see, if we let a1....ak be the whole A set and let b1...bl be the whole B set. Then by the property, any valuation of A which makes it be True, will make at least one of the b_i be true, thus eventually True. And all other valuation, will make the condition be false, and thus eventually be True. Thus tautology, what is the problem of this?

Comment: @qwerty  You don't have that $A$ and $B$ are finite ...

Comment: @qwerty Your proof sketch is precisely the right idea,  modulo the key issue that A and B could be infinite. This is where the Compactness Theorem comes to the rescue. You first use compactness to show that there are finite subsets A' of A and B' of B with the same property: any model of A' is a model of a sentence in B'. Then you can proceed with the argument you've written.

Comment: @halrankard2 ...Thanks for the hint, however, I still do not know how "a set of first-order sentences has a model if and only if every finite subset of it has a model" can help me to find such A' and B'. Especially the B' is actually a stronger requirement than B.

Comment: @qwerty Again, your confusion is arising because you have not determined which *unsatisfiable* set of sentences is relevant to the problem. Once you obtain this set, the significance of compactness will become much more clear. So I strongly suggest thinking more about the initial task. The assumption "every model of A is a model of some sentence in B" is **equivalent** to saying that a certain set of sentences is unsatisfiable. What is that set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Notice that the hypothesis says exactly that $\{\varphi,\neg \psi\mid \varphi\in A,\psi\in B\}$ is inconsistent. By compactness, there is a finite inconsistent subset.